# Why are Global Struct Variables not visible in Loop and in Function?

Tags: arduino, code

I created variables in a struct above void setup() so they would be Global.
Prior to this the code ran.
In Loop and in the one function I  get error the variables were not declared in this scope.
First error message is for Cap_Touch_State variable not declared in this scope (in Function "Cap_Touch_Function") which is two lines from bottom of the code below.  If I comment out all "Cap_Touch_State" lines, the error message the goes to next struct variable csSum.
Something wrong in how I am using struct.

I compared my code to other code with structs that works and cannot see where I have made a mistake.
Any help appreciated.

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

CapacitiveSensor   cs_25_26 = CapacitiveSensor(25,26);

struct CapTouch{
  int Cap_Touch_State;                
  unsigned long csSum;                
  unsigned long Touch_currentMillis;  
  unsigned long Touch_previousMillis;
  int elapsed_time;                   
};

CapTouch  Touch;

//Function Prototypes
CapTouch Cap_Touch_Function(CapTouch Touch);

void setup() 
{

//Define and initialize struct variables

Touch.Cap_Touch_State = 0;
Touch.csSum = 0;
Touch.Touch_currentMillis = 0;
Touch.Touch_previousMillis = 0;
Touch.elapsed_time = 0;

Serial.begin(250000);
}


void loop() 
{

Touch = Cap_Touch_Function(Touch);    // Calls Function gets values for Touch variables

Serial.print("Cap_Touch_State:  ");
Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State);          //  **ERROR MESSAGE HERE**
Serial.println();    

}


//FUNCTION CapTouch
CapTouch Cap_Touch_Function(CapTouch Touch){
int Trigger = 1000;   
int Threshold = 40;  
const long maxElapsed = 1500;

long cs = cs_25_26.capacitiveSensor(80); 

if (cs > Threshold)   
   { 
    Touch_previousMillis = Touch_currentMillis;   
    Touch_currentMillis = millis();
    elapsed_time = Touch_currentMillis -  Touch_previousMillis;  
    csSum = csSum + cs;   

     if (elapsed_time > maxElapsed)
      {
     csSum = 0;   
      } 
   }


if (csSum >= Trigger) //This is the sum threshold. At this point the "touch" has happened.
  {
     Cap_Touch_State = 1;
     csSum = 0; //Reset the sum
     cs_25_26.reset_CS_AutoCal(); //Recalibrate
  }

 else {Cap_Touch_State = 0;}

 Serial.print("Cap_Touch_State:  ");
 Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State);             //  **ERROR MESSAGE IS HERE**     
 return Cap_Touch_State;
}
```

---

Error Message Details:

```
C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\Rich Sketches\Debug_4_Cap_Touch\Debug_4_Cap_Touch.ino: In function 'void loop()':

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:39:18: error: 'Cap_Touch_State' was not declared in this scope

     Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State);          //  **ERROR MESSAGE HERE**

                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\Rich Sketches\Debug_4_Cap_Touch\Debug_4_Cap_Touch.ino:39:18: note: suggested alternative: 'Cap_Touch_Function'

     Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State);          //  **ERROR MESSAGE HERE**

                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                  Cap_Touch_Function

C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\Rich Sketches\Debug_4_Cap_Touch\Debug_4_Cap_Touch.ino: In function 'CapTouch Cap_Touch_Function(CapTouch)':

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:55:9: error: 'Touch_previousMillis' was not declared in this scope

         Touch_previousMillis = Touch_currentMillis;

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:55:32: error: 'Touch_currentMillis' was not declared in this scope

         Touch_previousMillis = Touch_currentMillis;

                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:57:9: error: 'elapsed_time' was not declared in this scope

         elapsed_time = Touch_currentMillis -  Touch_previousMillis;

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:58:9: error: 'csSum' was not declared in this scope

         csSum = csSum + cs;

         ^~~~~

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:67:9: error: 'csSum' was not declared in this scope

     if (csSum >= Trigger) //This is the sum threshold. At this point the "touch" has happened.

         ^~~~~

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:69:10: error: 'Cap_Touch_State' was not declared in this scope

          Cap_Touch_State = 1;

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\Rich Sketches\Debug_4_Cap_Touch\Debug_4_Cap_Touch.ino:69:10: note: suggested alternative: 'Cap_Touch_Function'

          Cap_Touch_State = 1;

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

          Cap_Touch_Function

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:74:12: error: 'Cap_Touch_State' was not declared in this scope

      else {Cap_Touch_State = 0;}

            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\Rich Sketches\Debug_4_Cap_Touch\Debug_4_Cap_Touch.ino:74:12: note: suggested alternative: 'Cap_Touch_Function'

      else {Cap_Touch_State = 0;}

            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            Cap_Touch_Function

Debug_4_Cap_Touch:77:19: error: 'Cap_Touch_State' was not declared in this scope

      Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State);             //  **ERROR MESSAGE IS HERE**

                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\Rich Sketches\Debug_4_Cap_Touch\Debug_4_Cap_Touch.ino:77:19: note: suggested alternative: 'Cap_Touch_Function'

      Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State);             //  **ERROR MESSAGE IS HERE**

                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                   Cap_Touch_Function

Using library arduino-libraries-CapacitiveSensor-a07209f at version 0.5.1 in folder: C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino-libraries-CapacitiveSensor-a07209f 
exit status 1
'Cap_Touch_State' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that subroutine you need to fully qualify the names of the structure members that yoy are trying to access. You pass "Touch" into the function and that needs to be used to qualify all the internal accesses.

You should consider several things that will make this better.

1. Use a different name for the argument to the subroutine than the name of the global structure variable.
2. Use a reference pointer to the global variable when you call the subroutine by passing the address of the global variable to the subroutine.
3. In the subroutine use the "pointer->member" type coding to reference the members of the passed in pointer.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the comment.  If I comment out the function call in Loop and the entire function itself,  I still get the error in Loop at line  "Serial.print(Cap_Touch_State); "

Comment: @RickH - For exactly the same reason. You cannot just use the "Cap_Touch_State" member name without qualifying what it belongs to.

Comment: Now I see (kind of).  The struct CapTouch contains Cap_Touch_State but CapTouch variables are members of "Touch".  I changed the code by adding "Touch." to become Touch.Cap_Touch_State and it works.   I know you mentioned giving a different name for the argument in the subroutine. Is this good coding practice?  It does work as same name, but not good practice?  Again, thanks.

Comment: @RickH - Using the same name in the subroutine is OK but can become confusing if you ever used that same subroutine to support calls to it that passed in different global structures. This is why I suggested you change the argument names in the subroutine. One could also argue that if you were only ever just using the single global structure then you should eliminate passing the structure to the subroutine and just directly address the global structure in the subroutine.